# using both navigation controller and tab bar controller in a view based application

Tags: xcode

I am making an view based application including both navigation controller and tab bar controller. I named program applic and both are working in applicViewController, but navigation bar is not showed in other classes that i named one, two and three.

Answer (score 0):

try this.If it is displayed then may it had hidden somewhere  self.navigationitem.Title=@"Title";